# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors for code without $?

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
BCG <- c(1,0)
cases <- c(101, 159)
controls <- c(46028, 34594)
BCG_model <- glm(cbind(cases, controls)~BCG, family = binomial)
```

The final line produces Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.

Why am I getting the Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors if I have no $? How can I make this model work?

Comment: The example is working fine for me (used R 4.0.3).  Can you do this on a fresh R session

Comment: I'm using 4.0.3 as well and have tried it in a new R session. I found that adding quotation marks around binomial made it work.

Comment: You might have an object named `binomial` in your environment. Try doing `rm(binomial)` and run the code again.